# Can we make the image of the week show up on the iphone theme?

Tags: feature-request, design

With the mobile theme now shown to iphone users, the image of the week is not available. One can see the title in big letters, but not the actual image:

[image: stack exchange screenshot]

Can we have the picture back, please? On this site, it's *more* than just decoration.

Comment: They call this a mobile theme?  Its pretty bad on the iPhone.

Comment: @dpollitt — and it's identical between all the sites, making it hard to tell them apart. But that's another issue. (Well, except for how the photo would help with that.)

Comment: I thought this was just a temporary solution. I REALLY REALLY hope it is, because this is neither very functional or good looking...

Comment: Getting rid of the right column (tags, Visit Meta, etc.) would do wonders.

Comment: I'm disappointed Matt, I had you pegged for a Droid user... ;)

Comment: JoanneC: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/whats-the-best-android-device-for-photography (Plus, Google is disturbingly non-open with Android.)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it from [talking to the designer, Jin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/941787#941787), the iPhone theme is common for all Stack sites, although that *might not* be the final theme.

I can see how removing the image may be helpful for mobile users with restricted download quotas/speeds though.